How to suppress "Batches" message in HuggingFace pipeline
I see the following message when I use a SentenceTransformer and then the text generation pipeline from transformers, and I can't seem to suppress it. How can I suppress it?
Batches: 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 41.27it/s]

This is at inference time, I am not training anything.
Thanks!

Try these 2 code:
1st:
import datasets  datasets.disable_progress_bar()

2nd: set disable_tqdm = True
from transformers import pipeline

model = pipeline("text-generation", model="gpt2", device=0)
output = model("any text", num_return_sequences=1, disable_tqdm=True)

